# ArrayOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

I can't write this exception and I'm hoping someone can show me how to.

I am trying to develop a `new Exception Class` called `Invalid Index Exception` which will inform the user of an attempt to access an invalid index in an array.

Then give a Java method only called `getValue()` which takes 2 parameters, an `integer (I)` representing the subscript and an `integer Array (A)`, and returns the element at position “I” in the Array “A”. This method should throw an Invalid Index Exception if “I” is not a valid index in the Array “A”.

Comment: What is blocking you from writing. Have a look here to learn about writing custom exceptions: http://java2novice.com/java_exception_handling_examples/create_custom_exception/

Comment: What exactly is your question or problem you are facing?

Comment: Why not just use an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: Why create your own new `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` class when Java already supplies its own [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) class?

Comment: @rgettman Could be an assignment

Comment: The out of bounds exceptions are runtime and thus, they are unchecked. Just asking here but do you intend to define your own exception so it can be checked? (forcing the catching when the method is invoked).

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to make a class that extends `Throwable` or `Exception`.  Then just perform whatever check you want to perform on the index in your `getValue` method and throw an instance of your custom exception when your 'invalid' condition is met.

However, if you currently try to access an invalid index of an array (such as -1 or `length`) Java will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, so you could just catch that.  If there is additonal logic you want to wrap around your array to throw it in some case that is not already covered, I'd recommend just using the existing exception, set your own message to it, and throw it on whatever condition you deem to be invalid.